# urllib2 is throwing an error for an url , while it's opening properly in browser

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to open an url through python like this

```
  import urllib2
  f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.futurebazaar.com/Search/laptop')
```

It's throwing following error

> File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py",
>   line 1134, in do_open
>       r = h.getresponse()   File "C:\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line
>   986, in getresponse
>       response.begin()   File "C:\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line
>   391, in begin
>       version, status, reason = self._read_status()   File
>   "C:\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line
>   355, in _read_status
>       raise BadStatusLine(line)   httplib.BadStatusLine

But this url is opening via browser.

Comment: What does your packet sniffer say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The website is broken.  If the optional "Accept" header isn't supplied, the site closes the connection without responding; this is invalid behavior.

Workaround:

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.futurebazaar.com/Search/laptop')
req.add_header('Accept', '*/*')
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: I just loaded the page in my browser and grabbed the HTTP headers it sent, compared it to the headers sent by urllib, then shifted headers one at a time until I found the one that was breaking the page.

Comment: that's great . Thanks once again for helping me out :)

Comment: I'm writing a script that syncs contacts from Exchange Server using Suds, and I kept intermittently getting this error. I usually don't like to mess with anything in site-packages, but I patched the suds http implementation with this fix and I haven't seen the error since. Perhaps I'll file a bug report with suds.  Thank you!

Comment: I spoke to soon. The error is back. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed the correct solution to my problem.