# Suds Error: BadStatusLine in httplib

Tags: python, soap, suds, httplib

I am using suds 0.3.6.  When creating a suds client, I randomly get an error:

httplib.py, _read_status(), line 355, class httplib.BadStatusLine'

Here is the code used to create the client:

```
imp = Import('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')
imp.filter.add('http://tempuri.org/encodedTypes')
imp.filter.add('http://tempuri.org/')
self.doctor = ImportDoctor(imp)

self.client = Client(self.URL,doctor=self.doctor)
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That means there is a problem on the server side which causes the HTTP server to reply with some junk instead of an ordinary 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' (or similar) line. You can't fix that.

Comment: I may get this error when creating the client then several seconds later try again and it will work.  What would cause the server to only occasionally send junk data?

Comment: Actually, anything from extremely high load (so high the server starts to glitch) to non-pure (whatever that means in functional languages) code.

Comment: After putting some prints in httplib.py, I found I was contacting www.w3.org and sometimes that site was sending back an empty string in the HTTP reply.  This is a related post I found:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505653/exchange-web-services-ews-exchange-2010-soap-calls-via-suds

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. To troubleshoot the problem, I turned on full suds logging:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger("suds.client").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger("suds.transport").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger("suds.xsd.schema").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger("suds.wsdl").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

With the debugging output, I noticed that the error occured when SUDS tried to download http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd (that particular schema was in some way referenced by the service I was trying to call). Turns out that the w3.org server is very overloaded ([link](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/site-comments/2011Apr/0026.html), [link](http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic/)).

The SUDS `Client` can be configured to use a cache. I implemented a cache object that returns the contents of two w3.org URLs that SUDS was hitting (you can find the URLs in the log output). I used a browser to fetch the two schemas and save them to disk and then put the contents as string contstants inside a source code file.

```
from suds.cache import NoCache
from suds.sax.parser import Parser

class StaticSudsCache(NoCache):
    def get(self, id):
        STATIC = {"http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd": XML_XSD,
                "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd": XMLSCHEMA_XSD }
        xml_string = STATIC.get(id.name)
        if xml_string:
            p = Parser()
            return p.parse(string=xml_string)

from suds.client import Client
c = Client(service_url, cache=StaticSudsCache())

XML_XSD = """... contents from file ..."""
XMLSCHEMA_XSD = """... contents from file ..."""
```

The full code including the XML schema content is [here](https://gist.github.com/1497343/).

Comment: thanks codeape, this solved my problem!, my suds is v0.4 and I made a "print id" before STATIC = ... line and I got: "6676093947907621806-document" so, I changed {"http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd": XML_XSD} for {"6676093947907621806-document": XML_XSD} and this started to work again.

Answer (score 1):

httplib is a pure python module.. you can have a look at the code for more precise information... 
BadStatusLine is raised if the status line can’t be parsed as a valid HTTP/1.0 or 1.1 status line. 
No solution as of now